# Javascript error (SCRIPT5022) in IE10

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I wrote this code:

```
AjxException.reportScriptError =
 function(ex) {
if (AjxException.reportScriptErrors && AjxException.scriptErrorHandler && !(ex    
       instanceof AjxException)) {
    AjxException.scriptErrorHandler(ex);
}
throw ex;
};
```

it's fine in all browsers including IE9,8 but I got this error in IE10:

```
 SCRIPT5022: InvalidCharacterError
```

mentioned `throw ex;`
Why this happens in IE10 and how could I solve this?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor (I'd recommend Notepad++ with the Hex plugin) and verify that there isn't any invisible character which could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually, I figured out what was wrong with the codes:
the javascript code was written for old versions of IE: `IE7, IE8, IE9` and used this line:

```
var ninput = document.createElement(AjxEnv.isIE ? ["<INPUT type='",type,"'>"].join("") :  
"INPUT");
```

in order to create INPUT element. it works fine in older versions of IE but not in `IE10`.
So, I had to use this one instead:

```
var ninput = document.createElement((AjxEnv.isIE && !AjxEnv.isIE10up)? ["<INPUT 
type='",type,"'>"].join("") : "INPUT");
```

now, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Are your files saved without a BOM (Byte Order Mark)? Those can often throw off parsers and wreak havoc.

I'd also recommend chopping up your code in to as many lines as possible to determine which line has the issue and then remove it for testing purposes and that way you'll be able to quickly determine what the issue is.

For example you may be referring to an object of the wrong type (working with an array and the object happens to be a string for example) so if you remove an object and it works (or works slightly better) try `alert('typeof myObject = '+typeof myObject);` to give you some further insight.

Also it looks like you have multiple instances of `ex`, make sure you aren't using a string *and* a function both named `ex`.